# Twitter Bootstrap Modal not appearing inside user view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal with dynamically generated content called #confirm, with no CSS modification as of the original Bootstrap 3 modal.
When I call $("#confirm").modal() it appears in a absolute position, always on the top of the page, not appearing for the user if the page is scrolled down.

That's the modal HTML:

```
<div id="confirm" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="moveConfirm">Add</button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The calling of the modal is made like this:

```
$('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
            .one('click', '#moveConfirm', function() {
                moveCard(card);
            });
```

As I said there is no CSS modification (so the .modal class is in fixed position), I do not know if this could mess this up but I have those CSS modification on the html and body elements:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 1; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 120%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

So, why isn't the modal appearing inside the user's screen always?

#### Edit

The page has dynamic content as well, in a div.*cards*, and I noticed none of this div's parents are following it's dynamic height. But if I set

```
.modal-dialog {
    top: 50%;
}
```

or any other percent, the modal appear to follow the real size of the page, not the one dictated by the window height. So I don't know if the height not increasing could be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got a way around it.
Using the [method](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/vertically-centering-bootstrap-modals) Abdelhakeem Osama referenced I changed the value passed to the css function (which changes the *margin-top*) to equals the *scrollTop* of the document, instead of the height of the window.
So my *reposition* function looks something like this:

```
function reposition() {
    var modal = $(this),
        dialog = modal.find('.modal-dialog');
    modal.css('display', 'block');
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
    dialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, top+15));
}
```

The +15 is there just so the modal isn't too close to the top of the user's screen, but can be modified to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/vertically-centering-bootstrap-modals

It defines a function to position the modal vertically to the center of the window and creates two event handlers to call that function whenever the modal is shown or the window is resized.

You may also try to tinker around your CSS styling rules on the *html* and *body* elements to find out whether it is these modifications that are causing the problem or not.

Comment: Unfortunately the function did not work, because the window height is not following the dynamic content of the page (none of the contents parents are, for the matter). Which my actually be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me get a way around it.
I would upvote you answer if I could.